# Solving non-linear equation in C using Newton's method?

Tags: c, probability, newtons-method

I have a non-linear equation defined as `p^(n-1) * [1-(1-p)^n] * r - c = 0`, where `n`, `r`, and `c` are given integers. I want to solve for `p` in the C programming language and decided to use Newton's method. I am wondering if this is the most suitable approach, and if there are other ways to solve this. (One important note that p stands for probability here, so it ranges from 0 to 1!)

Here is my current implementation, and it seems to work for some test cases but fails for others:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ld long double
#define TOLERANCE 1e-7
#define ITERATIONS 1000

ld function(ld p, int n, int c, int r) {
    return pow(p, n - 1) * (1 - pow(1 - p, n)) * r - c;
}

ld derivative(ld p, int n, int r) {
    return r * (n - 1) * pow(p, n - 2) * (1 - pow(1 - p, n)) + r * n * pow(p, n - 1) * pow(1 - p, n - 1);
}

ld pFinder(int n, ld c, ld r) {
    ld p = 0.5;

    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        ld fValue = function(p, n, c, r);
        ld fPrime = derivative(p, n, r);

        p = p - fValue / fPrime;

        if (fabs(fValue) < TOLERANCE) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    
    printf("Didn't converge after %d iterations", ITERATIONS);
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int n, c, r;

    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &c, &r);

    ld p = pFinder(n, c, r);

    printf("%.15Lf\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue arises with inputs like `18 30 2`, where the result is `1.999993641483941`, which is outside the valid range of `[0, 1]`. I do not understand why this is happening.

The constraints are `1 <= n <= 20`, `1 <= c <= 10000`, `1 <= r <= 10000`, and the absolute error of `p` is up to `10^-6`.

I appreciate any insights into what might be going wrong and how to improve my code!

P.S. This is my first time posting something here, and I am pretty new to coding, so I hope you don't mind that I'm not proficient in Markdown syntax!

Comment: Please don't use aliases or macros like `ld`, they don't make the code better in any way. Quite the opposite, they make the code harder to read and understand and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I can go modify them now 

Comment: "where the result is `1.999993641483941`, which is outside the valid range of `[0, 1]`" -- if that is occurring, then you have a problem with your math or range constraints. Double check your derivative and then look at the limit over the range of inputs. If you look at inputs, say `5 5 5` (converges to `1`), but `6 6 6` (converges to `1.9946...`), that either says your math is wrong, or your input ranges are wrong. Also, you can't use `scanf()` correctly unless you ***check the return***. A simple `if (scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &c, &r) != 3) { return 1; }` will do.

Comment: You want a solution in [0, 1], but nothing in p^(n-1) * [1-(1-p)^n] * r - c = 0 constrains the solution to be in [0, 1]. The value found, 1.999993641483941, is a correct solution to that equation, with some allowance for rounding in computation.

Comment: I had not considered those simple scenarios where the same problem arises. Your insights have been very helpful, and now I have a clear idea what to do next! I also appreciate the scanf() check you shared – it's something I was not aware of before, and I will go implement it right now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see, I might need to read my question again, to come up with the correct formula and I am getting a sense that I might have to begin the entire process anew :(

Comment: Maybe try bisection instead of Newton's method. It is slower (takes more iterations to reach a specified accuracy) but it is more reliable (can't fly off into infinity or otherwise leave the interval or get into a cycle).

Comment: Oooh I will look into this method! Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *p* to be in [0,1], *c/r* must also be in [0,1]. In that case, if you start with *p* = 1 (instead of *p* = 0.5), Newton's method will be well-behaved and will very quickly arrive at the desired precision. Much faster than bisection. The number of iterations will be small. For your tolerance, I can't get them to be more than 16. Usually just a handful.

In your example "10 30 2", *c/r* is 15, which is not in [0,1]. Check for *c <= r* before proceeding. (Your *c >= 1* and *r >= 1* already assures that *c/r >= 0*.)

Your use of `pow()` eliminates any precision advantage of using long doubles. Use `powl()` instead. Also `fabsl()`.

To update, you only need two `powl()`'s, which are slow. I would:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

long double root(int n, int c, int r) {
    assert(n >= 1 && c >= 0 && r >= 1 && c <= r);
    int k = n - 1;
    long double x = c / (long double)r, p = 1;
    for (;;) {
        long double q = 1 - p, s = powl(q, k), t = powl(p, k),
                    d = t * (1 - q * s) - x;
        if (fabsl(d) < 1e-7L)
            return p;
        p -= p * d / (t * (k + s * (p * (2 * k + 1) - k)));
    }
}
```

If I had to do this a lot, I would use an integer power algorithm. It's about three times as fast as `powl()`, which handles non-integer exponents that do not occur here.

```c
long double pownl(long double x, unsigned n) {
    long double p = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (n & 1)
            p *= x;
        n >>= 1;
        if (n == 0)
            return p;
        x *= x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your clarification regarding the need of and additional condition to limit the range of c/r. I understood why my code was exhibiting unexpected behavior. It is also enlightening to discover powl() and fabsl(), specifically for long double type. Grateful for your mention of the integer power algorithm; perhaps I will encounter a problem where this method would be useful in the future. Thank you so much for taking your time to address my question!! ☺️